# Logical volumes are not activated on boot

Tags: lvm, boot

Ubuntu 22.04.1 here. I have a volume group called `system` created during installation. There are three logical volumes in this group.

```
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/system/swap
  LV Name                swap
  VG Name                system
  LV UUID                qeGYCG-PseM-IzIW-rpit-0zwI-lbKs-q0jL8D
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ubuntu-server, 2022-12-02 19:20:46 +0000
  LV Status              NOT available
  LV Size                1,00 GiB
  Current LE             256
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
   
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/system/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                system
  LV UUID                qx6W1r-e20x-VfwG-1Sdg-uGE3-rRW9-89k24O
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ubuntu-server, 2022-12-02 19:20:47 +0000
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                10,00 GiB
  Current LE             2560
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:0
   
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/system/drbd
  LV Name                drbd
  VG Name                system
  LV UUID                rQxv3f-pJds-JU1z-9Hqd-hi81-3kAt-zlcVbh
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ubuntu-server, 2022-12-02 19:20:49 +0000
  LV Status              NOT available
  LV Size                <21,00 GiB
  Current LE             5375
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
```

This is an output of `lvdisplay` command right after a reboot. On every reboot logical volume `swap` and `drbd` isn't activated. I need to use `vgchange -ay` command to activate them by hand. Only `root` logical volume is available, on this volume system is installed. Adding volume names to `auto_activation_volume_list` in `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf` does not help.

Why does this happen?

**Update #1**

I tried to recreate logical volume. First I removed the swap volume, then recreated it with a different name. Still same problem after reboot. Volume is not activated till `vgchange -ay`.

Comment: What is the content of `/etc/sysconfig/lvm`?

Comment: This is Ubuntu, not Centos/Redhat/any_rpm_distro. No such file on Ubuntu.

Comment: I also have this problem.  Tried disabling `udev_rules` in `lvm.conf` to fall back on LVM's default 'activate everything' behaviour, but still Logical Volumes aren't activate on boot until `vgchange -ay`